# How much memory Java needs to start?

Tags: java, ubuntu, memory-management

This is my script (I'm just trying to experiment to fix a bigger problem):

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx64m"
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -version &
done
```

In a nutshell, I'm trying to start 10 java processes at the same time. The server has 512Mb of RAM and 4Gb of swap. That should be more than enough for ten processes 64Mb each. However, this is what I see in the output for two of them:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for the card marking array
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for code cache
```

Why this is happening? How to resolve?

Crashed processes created files with this start:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 160088 bytes for HashtableBucket in /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u21-2.3.9/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/hashtable.inline.hpp
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
```

Which of the following is my case?

Comment: I am not sure about it but I think that when you start a JVM, it takes all the memory given in args at startup. Hence, you need 640M...

Comment: You mean that swap of 4Gb is not considered as memory for JVM?

Comment: `-Xmx` defines the maximum heap size - the whole Java process uses more memory than that.

Comment: Still should be far less than 4Gb available, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Java reserves some memory that must be physical memory (not swap) at start up for internal management of the VM. If you do not have enough physical memory the JVM will not start.

Comment: Is it a configurable parameter? Can you give some link that explains this please?

Comment: @yegor256 No there is no parameter and I did not found any reference for this. But there are some structures that need to be in memory, but as I said I found no reference.